# SELECT ONE WORD FROM ONE STATEMENT

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have rule_query table 
which has number of query with constant variable appends to each query .
In every query , variable takes input from another table, appends it  and execute that query as result.

But i want to return that variable too i.e coming from another table and appends here in query of rule_query table.

I want to know for what value of variable which append on this query and execution done

```
RULE_QUERY
----------
SELECT GMID FROM @FIPSNAME+ADMIN1
SELECT GMID FROM @FIPSNAME+ADMIN2
SELECT GMID FROM @FIPSNAME+ADMIN3

COUNTRYTABLE
USA
UK
FRA
SA
```

In every value of  countrytable loop i am able to get gmid value.
But i am not able to get for what from country table does this gmid returns.

Kindly suggest solutions.

Comment: Please do not use caps lock

Comment: CAPS lock in internet is equivalent to yelling in real life.

Comment: CAPS lock yield a LION ROAR .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select

```
 SELECT GMID, @FIPSNAME FROM @FIPSNAME+ADMIN1
```

or

```
SELECT @FIPSNAME FROM @FIPSNAME+ADMIN1
```

or

```
 SELECT  @FIPSNAME+ADMIN1 FROM @FIPSNAME+ADMIN1
```